# Hash and Modular Arthmetic

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, hash, modular-arithmetic

Let **`h(y)`** be the function defined as **`(a*y+b)mod m`**. So `h(y)` can take values `from 0 to m-1.`
Now we are given 7 integers- `a,b,x,n,c,d,m`. Our task is to find the total count of `h(x),h(x+1),h(x+2)...h(x+n)` such that the value of `h(x+i)` falls in the range of `[c,d]`.where `0<=i<=n`
Integer limits are:

```
1 ≤ m ≤ 10^15, c ≤ d < m, a,b < m, x+n ≤ 10^15, and a*(x+n) + b ≤ 10^15
```

For Example.
for input `set {1,0,0,8,0,8,9}` the output should be 9. Please suggest an efficient algorithm. Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a particularly strong hash. The only hard part about this problem is the obtuse notation with single-letter variables and specifying the problem as a 7-tuple.

Each increment of `x` increases `h(x)` by `a`. Therefore the total distance along `x` to get from `c` to `d` is simply **`(d-c)/a`**. Add one for the fencepost problem, or specify the problem with a half-open range for the sake of sanity.